# SQL query in Pro-C fails with Error:02115

Tags: sql, c, oracle-pro-c, embedded-sql

I am getting some weird behavior of Pro-C procedure as shown below:

```
#define BGHCPY_TO_ORA(dest, source) \
{ \
(void)strcpy((void*)(dest).arr, (void*)(source)); \
(dest).len = strlen((const char *)(dest).arr); \
}
#define BGHCPY_FROM_ORA(dest, source) \
{ \
(void)memcpy((void*)(dest), (void*)(source).arr, (size_t)(source).len); \
(dest)[(source).len] = '\0'; \
} 

long fnSQLMarkProcessed (char *pszRowId, char *pszMarker)
{
  BGHCPY_TO_ORA (O_rowid_stack,    pszRowId);
  BGHCPY_TO_ORA (O_cust_processed, pszMarker);

  EXEC SQL
       UPDATE  document_all
          SET  processed_by_bgh = :O_cust_processed
        WHERE  rowid = :O_rowid_stack;

  return (sqlca.sqlcode);
}
```

The input arguments values passed to above function is

```
pszRowId = [AAAF1lAAIAABOoRAAB], pszMarker=X
```

The query return the error code:02115 with following message:

```
SQL Error:02115 Code interpretation problem -- check COMMON_NAME usage
```

I am using Oracle as the backend database.

**Can anyone provide me information on what are the possible causes for this failed query?**

Any help is highly appreciated.

Flags used during PRO-C Compilation is defined below:

```
------/u01/app/oracle/product/8.1.6/ORACLE_HOME/bin/proc `echo  -Dbscs5 -Dsun5 -I/export/home/bscsobw/bscs6/src/CoreDumpIssue/final_Code_Fix_004641  -DNDEBUG -DSunOS53 -D_POSIX_4SOURCES -I/usr/generic++/generic++2.5.3.64_bit/include  -DFEATURE_212298 -DBSCS_CONFIG -I/export/home/bscsobw/bscs6//src/bat/include -DFEATURE_00203808_GMD -DFEATURE_00241737  -DORACLE_DB_BRAND -I/u01/app/oracle/product/8.1.6/ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/demo -I/u01/app/oracle/product/8.1.6/ORACLE_HOME/precomp/public -I/export/home/bscsobw/bscs6/src/CoreDumpIssue/final_Code_Fix_004641/include -I../bat/include -DFEATURE61717 -DFEATURE52824 -DFEATURE56178 -DD236312_d -DSDP -g | sed -e 's/-I/INCLUDE=/g' -e 's/-D[^ ]=[^ ]*//g' -e 's/-D\([^ ]*\)/DEFINE=\1/g'` select_error=no   DEFINE=FEATURE61717 DEFINE=FEATURE52824 DEFINE=FEATURE56178 \
                lines=yes iname=bgh_esql.pc oname=bgh_esql.c lname=bgh_esql.lis
```

Comment: This is not Oracle PL/SQL code.

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake, this is the code segment from Pro-C. there is an intermittent behavior shown by "fnSQLMarkProcessed" procedure.

Comment: Please show the complete compiler command line.

Comment: Has O_rowid_stack and O_cust_processed been allocated/defined elsewhere??

Comment: @TonyB: These are defined as the global variable VARCHAR    O_rowid_stack[20];           /* current rowid on stack       */           VARCHAR    O_cust_processed[2];

Comment: @OldProgrammer: I have edited the question to add the options used in compilation of PRO-C source file. Please check

Comment: You might like to successivly comment out one line after the other to identify the exact line causing the trouble.

Comment: Are O_rowid_stack and O_cust_processed in a declare section?

    EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
        // declarations...
    EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

Answer (score 1):

I think, you check this message:

```
[oracle@sb-rac02 ~]$ oerr sql 2115
02115, 00000, "Code interpretation problem -- check COMMON_NAME usage"
// *Cause: With PRO*FORTRAN, this error occurs if the precompiler option
//         COMMON_NAME is specified incorrectly.  **With other Oracle
//         Precompilers, this error occurs when the precompiler cannot
//         generate a section of code.**
// *Action: With Pro*FORTRAN, when using COMMON_NAME to precompile two or
//          more source modules, make sure to specify a different common name
//          for each module.  With other Oracle Precompilers, if the error
//          persists, call customer support for assistance.
```

So you can determine, that problem not in your variables.

Please, try use your code like this:

```
long fnSQLMarkProcessed (char *pszRowId, char *pszMarker)
{
  BGHCPY_TO_ORA (O_rowid_stack,    pszRowId);
  BGHCPY_TO_ORA (O_cust_processed, pszMarker);

  EXEC SQL UPDATE  document_all
          SET  processed_by_bgh = :O_cust_processed
        WHERE  rowid = :O_rowid_stack;

  return (sqlca.sqlcode);
}
```